# The image of homomorphism of fundamental group of closed surface

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, gn.general-topology

$\phi: \pi_1(S)\to \pi_1(S)$ is a homomorphism of fundamental group of closed orientable surface $S$ of genus >=2. If $\phi$ is not an epimorphism, can we find a non-surjective self map $f: S\to S$ induces $\phi$ such that $f(S)$ be a submanifold embedded in $S$?

Comment: Could the people voting to close please explain why?

Comment: Taking $\mathbb{T}^2= S^1 \times S^1$, the real $2$-torus, one has $\pi_1(\mathbb{T}^2)=\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$. Taking as $\phi$ the projection onto one of the factors, it seems to me that the image of the corresponding self-map $\mathbb{T}^2 \to \mathbb{T}^2$ is a copy of $S^1$.

Comment: @MarkGrant: I voted to close because it is more suitable for MSE. To begin with, it is based on a false premise that non-epimorphism can be induced by a non-surjective map (think of finite covers of the torus to itself); however, this false premise does hold in the higher genus case (why?). Secondly, any continuous map $f: M^m\to N^n$ is homotopic to a surjective map (think of a Peano curve).

Comment: I mean: can we find a non-surjective self map f:S→S such that  
f(S) is a submanifold.

Comment: @Misha, since you say it would be more suitable on MSE, I wonder why you didn't vote to migrate it there?

Comment: @J.C.Wu, you might be interested in Scott's paper 'Subgroups of surface groups are almost geometric'.

Comment: @HJRW: Yes, I should have, but I was doing this on a tiny screen...